# Unable to pass the login page in Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Below is my controller class

```
@RestController
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return "<h1>Welcome All</h1>";
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String user(){
        return "<h1>Welcome User</h1>";
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public String admin(){
        return "<h1>Welcome Admin</h1>";
    }
   }
```

Below is my SpringSecurityConfig class.

```
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");

    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder(){
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

             http
                  .authorizeRequests()
                  .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                  .antMatchers("/user").hasRole("USER")
                  .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                  .and().formLogin();

    }
}
```

I'm not able to pass the login page. When I enter the user name and password it redirects back to the login page. Even I have enabled the csrf disable but still it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your password Encoder is creating problem.

Try this

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    String user = passwordEncoder().encode("user");
    String admin = passwordEncoder().encode("admin");
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password(user).roles("USER")
            .and()
            .withUser("admin").password(admin).roles("ADMIN");
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

or if you want to keep `NoOpPasswordEncoder` as encoder

change your `inmemoryAuthentication` like this if you are using `Spring Security 5`

This will delegate password encoder to  `NoOpPasswordEncoder`.

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("{noop}user").roles("USER")
            .and()
            .withUser("admin").password("{noop}admin").roles("ADMIN");
}
```

If this doesn't work. Please look for any error in log and add log.

**Edit 1:**

For 403 error please add httpBasic() in your configuration

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http
              .httpBasic()
              .and()
              .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
              .antMatchers("/user").hasRole("USER")
              .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
              .and().formLogin();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have been able to overcome by adding the annotation @EnableWebSecurity  in SpringSecurityConfig class. 
But now i'm facing a different problem that is i'm able to login to the http://localhost:8080/. 
But i'm not able to login to the http://localhost:8080/user or http://localhost:8080/admin. 
Even I have followed your method but still didn't work out. Appreciate your help on this

Comment: I'm getting a 403 ((type=Forbidden, status=403).) error while login to the localhost:8080/user or localhost:8080/admin. No error logs in the console

Comment: Now it shows an error. Can't able to add both .httpBasic() and .authorizeRequests()

Comment: I think and is missing. try now

Comment: thanks for ur help. It's working and now when i enter localhost:8080/admin it prompts for the login form and when i enter the credential it is able to successfully login but it redirects to the  localhost:8080/  but when i enter the localhost:8080 it displays the result.
So now what my question is how to prompt the /admin when i enter the admin credentials.
Anyway thanks you fixed the above problem